# Meteor Crosswalk build fails at second 'ant debug' step

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, apk, crosswalk-runtime

I have a Meteor Cordova Android app which I'm trying to migrate and build using Crosswalk. I followed the steps from here:
https://meteor.hackpad.com/Building-Meteor-app-with-Crosswalk-kHKh4DzGxFQ

Until here, the build succeeds.

```
android update project --subprojects --path . --target "android-19"
ant debug
cd ..

ant clean
```

The next step, `ant release` or `ant debug`, the build fails with 100 javac errors. The error log is very close to whats mentioned here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3076

The solution partly is here:

https://github.com/RayHuo/MyXwalk/wiki/MIGRATE-AN-EXISTING-CORDOVA-APPLICATION-TO-CROSSWALK-WITH-CORDOVA-3.4-OR-LATER. 
Its says:

> "And the solution is to changing the second ant debug to cordova build android"

But the android project folder is generated by Meteor and not Cordova, so I do not have cordova executable installed to run a `cordova build android`.
I still tried installing cordova separately and building it, but it simply says, 'its not a cordova based project'.

How do we do the last step using Meteor? There is another option to build it [using Eclipse/ADT](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html#Migrate-using-ADT), but I want to figure this out within the Meteor build process.
I know I'm missing something simple here. Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

crosswalk provides a HelloWorld cordova/example via the bin/create
utility on the intel crosswalk website.

that CordovaLib directory can replace the meteor equivalent
,however the latest meteor version fails, so there maybe some
crosswalk/meteor version problems now to resolve.

HelloWorld appears to work with old version 8 crosswalk
and new meteor build
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/develop_an_application.html

Answer (score 0):

Meteor 1.2 now supports CrossWalk with `$ meteor add crosswalk`